# indexing a 3D batched tensor in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, indexing, slice

I have a 3D tensor params with size (Nx128x3), where N is the batchsize.

I have also an index tensor indices=(Nx16) which holds the indicies in the second dimension of the A. I want to fetch the entire row for a given index so that the result would be (Nx16x3).

Currently I am using the following code

`gathered = tf.reshape(tf.gather(tf.reshape(params,-1,int(params.shape[2])]),tf.reshape(indices,[-1,])),[-1,int(indices.shape[1]),int(params.shape[2])])`

Is there a way to write this by using gather_nd?

-- My current full code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

N = 10
params = tf.constant(np.random.randn(N, 128, 3), dtype=tf.float32)
indices = tf.constant(np.random.randint(0, 128, [N,16]), dtype=tf.int32)

gathered = tf.reshape(tf.gather(tf.reshape(params,[-1,int(params.shape[2])]),tf.reshape(indices,[-1,])),[-1,int(indices.shape[1]),int(params.shape[2])])

with tf.Session() as sess:
    result = sess.run(gathered)
print('params: ',params.shape)
print('ind: ',indices.shape)
print('result: ',result.shape)
```

Comment: For fetching an entire row, `gather` does the job, why you want to use `gather_nd`?. For `gather_nd`, you need to get the indices of all the elements in the row, not so efficient.

Comment: your might be right, but i still don't get the clue about how to do that for this case.